# Django update migrations from sqlalchemy to south

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, django-migrations, alembic

I've a django project which was using alembic and sql alchemy for migrations. I'd upgraded django to 1.9 which has south by default for migrations. Is there any way to switch to south for adding and removing of new fields without creating migrations for tables?

I'd tried python manage.py makemigrations  but it is creating migrations for tables that already exists.

Comment: fake or fake initial migrate will help you here

Comment: South is an external app for pre-1.7 migrations. Migrations in 1.7+ are called Django core migrations, or simply migrations. I've changed the tags accordingly.